# Idiomatic way of wrapping a returned error inside a function

Tags: rust

I keep coming across the pattern in rust. My solution seems very verbose. Wondering if there a more idiomatic way of accomplishing the same thing.

I have function that about half way through might error. I need to either, get the result and keep processing or return an error. The error needs to a custom type and have some context.

```
async fn load_data() -> Result<SomeOutput, MyError> {
    ...

    let raw = match str::from_utf8(&output.stdout) {
        Ok(o) => o,
        Err(e) => {
            return Err(MyError::FailedParse(
                "failed to read output from command X".into(),
                e.to_string(),
            ));
        }
    };

    ...
        
}
```

I've looked into adding a `From` trait to the original error type, but then that error will always be converted into that type. I'd like more control about what error type is returned when.

Answer (score 2):

Depends a bit on what *exactly* you need.

For starters, there's of course the `?` operation. Not sure if operator is the right word. Of course that requires that the `From` trait for the underlying error is implemented for your error type, and it lacks the control you seek.

So then there's the various methods implemented on `Result`. You could use `map_err` to convert the underlying error to the error you actually want to return.

That can become quite a bit more cumbersome than you'd like, so there's also two crates to check out: `anyhow` and `thiserror`

Comment: The `From` approach is super great when you can work it in there, near-zero-effort error conversion.